# No overload for 'Application_DocumentOpen' matches delegate

Tags: c#, vsto, word-addins

We are creating a new Word add-in project in C#

We implemented the code below in `private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)`

```
this.Application.DocumentOpen += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentOpenEventHandler(Application_DocumentOpen);
```

we compile above code, it is getting below Error.

> error CS0123: No overload for 'Application_DocumentOpen' matches delegate 'ApplicationEvents4_DocumentOpenEventHandler'

We don't understand this error. How can we implement events in Word application?

Comment: You are not passing a delegate as expected, but instead an new object instance.

Comment: can you please give me snippet how to pass delegate ?

Comment: This is more or less what I have in a Word Add-in... The only thing I can think of is that the version of Office which the add-in targets doesn't support this interface. Did you generate this by pressing TAB after typing `+=`? And you then pressed TAB again to generate a stub for `Application_DocumentOpen` listed in the parentheses?

Comment: resolve this issue.

Comment: @Dimitar do you know which event handler use for word double click event.?